# npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists while npm intall command in docker

Tags: docker

This is my docker file content and I am getting this error

> npm ERR! Tracker "idealTree" already exists

```
WORKDIR ../../
RUN npm cache clear --force
RUN npm install
CMD ["npm", "start"]

ADD package*.json ./
RUN npm ci --production
```

and this is my folder structure

[image]

Comment: Are you running `npm install` and then again running `npm ci` in the same build stage?  Is the Dockerfile you quoted missing a `FROM` line, or more than one?